# Bitcoin API currency converter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to do my own bitcoin currency converter. The link to check the currency rate is:

> https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=1000

So I did a HTML form, with one input, where the user will give me the value in USD he wants to check how many BTC's it's on the moment.

```
<form class="searchform" name="BTCValueForm" action="" method="POST">
U$<input type="text" name="usd" id="usd" maxlength="5">
 - BTC = <p id="btcvalue"> </p>
 <p> <input name="Exchange" type="submit" class="button" onclick="return BitcoinRate(BTCValueForm)" value="Check"> </p>

</form>
```

Ok, the button calls javascript function BitcoinRate, what is:

```
function BitcoinRate(BTCValueForm)
{
    load('https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value='+BTCValueForm.usd.value,'BitcoinRate'); 
}
```

Function load is:

```
 function load(url,reason) {
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var Answer = xmlhttp.responseText;
if (reason == 'BitcoinRate') {
                document.getElementById('btcvalue').innerHTML = Answer; 
            }
    xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

It's supposed to get the answer from the API, and put in the paragraph "btcvalue" in the form. But looking on Chrome's debugger I see the GET request is cancelled before it starts. What's happening here? Any clues?

Comment: Sorry... What you mean?

Comment: Does blockchain.info send the respective [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), so that you can use the content in your page?

Comment: Uhmm... I didn't knew this. I need to put some respective header for this or what?

Comment: You don't, but the server (blockchain.info) needs to add some headers, if they want you to be able to use their stuff on your page.

Comment: And what I should do in this case?

Comment: Check, if they send the appropriate headers. If not, there is nothing you can do (clientside). You could then just retrieve the data on the server side using PHP, Java, JS, ...

Comment: Did some testing also and couldn't get any AJAX calls to retrieve data from their servers for the "tobtc" or the "ticker" page (tobtc was canceled and ticker returned a blank response).  Here is a forum discussion about this: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=293292.0.  Sounds like you can't access that data from client and will have to do it server side unfortunately.

Comment: You also might want to try scraping the html of the tobtc result using YQL.  I wasn't able to get it to work easily in my jsfiddle test but it looks like it might yield some result with some effort: http://www.abdullahyahya.com/2012/09/08/using-jquery-to-screen-scrape-html-from-a-different-site-jquery-curl/ or http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/660151/Screen-scraping-using-YQL-and-AJAX

Answer (score 2):

I'll recommend [CurrencyFreaks API](https://currencyfreaks.com/) as you can get Bitcoin currency conversion in the world's 179 currencies compatible with various programming languages such as Shell, Node.js, Java, Python, PHP, Ruby, JS, C#, C, Go, Swift.

**Here I'm giving Bitcoin converter endpoint using JavaScript:**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
  if(this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("GET", "https://api.currencyfreaks.com/latest/convert
    ?apikey=YOUR_APIKEY
    &from=USD&to=BTC
    &amount=10000");

xhr.send();
```

The JSON response will be as follows:

```
{
    "date": "2020-10-06 05:44:00+00",
    "current_rates": {
        "USD": "1.0",
        "BTC": "0.00009296030223253462"
    },
    "converted_amount": "0.9296030223253462",
    "query": {
        "given_amount": "10000.0",
        "from": "USD",
        "to": "BTC"
    }
}
```

I hope it will be the easiest solution for the BTC converter.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that BlockChain did not permit their CORS(Cross Origin Resource Sharing).
I will recommend you use [CryptoCompare API](https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/#) and it's free. My answer below might help you with what you are looking for.

```
<form class="searchform" name="BTCValueForm" action="" method="POST">
  - U$<input type="text" name="usd" id="usd" maxlength="5">
  - BTC = <p id="btcvalue"> </p>
 <p> <input name="Exchange" type="submit" class="button" onclick="return 
  BitcoinRate()" value="Check"> </p>

</form>
```

I will be using cryptocompare API for the Xml, to get the price of btc

```
function BitcoinRate(){
    var btc = document.querySelector('#btcvalue'),
    amount = document.querySelector('#usd').value

    var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    XHR.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(XHR.readyState == 4 && XHR.status == 200){
            console.log(data)
            var data = JSON.parse(XHR.responseText)
            // Divide the given amount with the current price of one BTC to USD = BTC amount
            let BTC_amount = amount / data.USD
            // You can round up the BTC_amount to your desired value
            let final_value = BTC_amount.toFixed(3);
            // Equate the final_value to the btc var, to display it
            btc.innerText = final_value;
        } else {
            alert('something went wrong')
        }
    }
    // Note: here I used BTC to USD, but you can use a different coin or fiat currency supported by CC API
    var url = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD';

    XHR.open('GET', url);
    XHR.send();

}
```

Using JQuery with keypress(), it is more cleaner than XML request(dry)

```
var amount = jQuery('#usd').val(),
    btc    = jQuery('#btcvalue')
jQuery('#usd').keypress(function(event){
    if ( event.which == 13 ) {
       event.preventDefault();
    }
    $.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD",function(data){
     let BTC_amount = amount / data["USD"],
         final_value = BTC_amount.toFixed(3)
     btc.text(final_value)
    });
})
```